# JSON to JavaScript variable via AJAX and PHP MYSQL => Array undefined

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

i am trying to get mysql data via php -> json -> ajax into my JS variables for Chartjs.
The JSON generated by php looks totally fine. Unfortunately when trying to get the data in my variables the console returns them as undefined.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("---");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT clanarina, vakufnama, zekjat, year from payments where uid = 1");


$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
mysqli_close($con);
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

JSON:

```
    [{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"12500","zekjat":"0","year":"2019"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2021"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2022"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2023"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2024"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2025"}]
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : "../../getchartdata_payments_user.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data){
      console.log(data);

      var clanarinajs = [];
      var vakufnamajs = [];
      var zekjatjs = [];


      for(var i in data) {
        clanarinajs.push(data[i].clanarina);
        vakufnamajs.push(data[i].vakufnama);
        zekjatjs.push(data[i].zekjat);
      }
      console.log(clanarinajs);
      console.log(vakufnamajs);
      console.log(zekjatjs);
      var chartdata = {
        labels: ["2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024","2025"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Clanarina",
            backgroundColor: "#4e73df",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "#2e59d9",
            borderColor: "#4e73df",
            data: clanarinajs
          },
          {
            label: "Vakufnama",
            backgroundColor: "#aafac8",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "#2e59d9",
            borderColor: "#4e73df",
            data: vakufnamajs
          },
          {
            label: "Zekjat",
            data: zekjatjs
          },
          {
            label: "Goal",
            data: [54000, 54000, 55620, 57289, 59007, 60777, 62601],
            type: "line",
            fill: "false",
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            borderColor: "yellow",
          }
        ]
      };

      var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");

      var mybarchart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartdata,
        options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 10,
              right: 25,
              top: 25,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              time: {
                unit: 'year'
              },
              gridLines: {
                display: false,
                drawBorder: false
              },
              maxBarThickness: 25,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: 70000,
                maxTicksLimit: 5,
                padding: 10,
                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  return 'KM' + number_format(value);
                }
              },
              gridLines: {
                color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                drawBorder: false,
                borderDash: [2],
                zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
              }
            }],
          },
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          tooltips: {
            titleMarginBottom: 10,
            titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
            titleFontSize: 14,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
            bodyFontColor: "#858796",
            borderColor: '#dddfeb',
            borderWidth: 1,
            xPadding: 15,
            yPadding: 15,
            displayColors: false,
            caretPadding: 10,
            callbacks: {
              label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
                var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                return datasetLabel + ': KM' + number_format(tooltipItem.yLabel);
              }
            }
          },
        }
      });
    },
  });
});
```

Console Output:

```
[{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"12500","zekjat":"0","year":"2019"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2021"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2022"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2023"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2024"},{"clanarina":"240","vakufnama":"0","zekjat":"0","year":"2025"}] chart-bar-demo.js:10:15

Array(385) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, … ]
chart-bar-demo.js:22:15

Array(385) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, … ]
chart-bar-demo.js:23:15

Array(385) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, … ]
chart-bar-demo.js:24:15
```

As you can see console.log(data) also works fine but pushing the data in the variables seems to be a problem.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `clanarinajs` contains 6 elements (from 0 to 5), but you have defined 7 labels in your `chartdata`, from 2019 to 2025, i.e. the chart is expecting `clanarinajs[6]` as well, which is undefined. Same for other `...js` variables you are using as values for `data` parameters in chartdata. Try to remove 2025 and let us know the result. In any case you have to do JSON parse of `data` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON returned by the PHP is still a string at the point at which you push into the arrays. You'll notice that the array lengths correspond to the length of the string.

You'll need to parse the JSON string into a JS array before you loop over it, which you can do using `JSON.parse();`

Comment: I tried it with $.parseJSON(data).
Now im getting Array(6) [undefined, undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]

console log:
0: Object { clanarina: "240", vakufnama: "12500", zekjat: "0", … }
1: Object { clanarina: "0", vakufnama: "0", zekjat: "0", … }
​2: Object { clanarina: "240", vakufnama: "0", zekjat: "0", … }
​3: Object { clanarina: "240", vakufnama: "0", zekjat: "0", … }
​4: Object { clanarina: "240", vakufnama: "0", zekjat: "0", … }
​5: Object { clanarina: "240", vakufnama: "0", zekjat: "0", … }
​6: Object { clanarina: "240", vakufnama: "0", zekjat: "0", … }

Comment: If you're using jQuery 3.0+, they now recommend using the native `JSON.parse()` see [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).
Also I'm not able to reproduce this using the code you've posted above - both `$.parseJSON` and `JSON.parse()` give me an object array of length 6 from which I can loop over to get the values you want.

Comment: The array i get from json.parse seems to be fine but when looping over it im getting 3 arrays of the correct lengh but the content is undefined. Something from with my loop ?

Comment: Just to confirm - you've got `var array= JSON.parse(data)` and you're looping like this?
`var clanarinajs = []; var vakufnamajs = []; var zekjatjs = [];`

`for (var i in array) {
 clanarinajs.push(array[i].clanarina);
 vakufnamajs.push(array[i].vakufnama);
 zekjatjs.push(array[i].zekjat);
});`

Comment: Did it like that:
var datanew = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(datanew);
      var clanarinajs = [];
      var vakufnamajs = [];
      var zekjatjs = [];


      for(var i in datanew) {
        clanarinajs.push(data[i].clanarina);
        vakufnamajs.push(data[i].vakufnama);
        zekjatjs.push(data[i].zekjat);
      }

Comment: Ah - you need to push `datanew[i].XXXX` not `data[i].XXXX`

Comment: aaah yes thats it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad I could help.